# Turning on syntax highlighting in vim causes warning message

Tags: macos, vim

I'm wanting to turn on syntax highlighting in vim using the .exrc file and using the following commands:

```
syntax on
syntax=html
```

Every time I open a file I get the following message now:

> No Syntax items defined for this buffer

I'm using VIM version 7.3 on OS X 10.10.4

Comment: I don't mind to use .vimrc as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

For more information see:

```
:h :filetype
:h :syntax
:h filetype
```

Comment: Error detected while processing /Users/username/.vimrc:
line    3:
E475: Invalid argument: ident on

Comment: You are missing the `n` in `indent`.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to set `'syntax'` manually, you’d need a `:set syntax=html`. But the simpler way is to just open `foo.html` and `:syntax on`. That should trigger a few settings (like `filetype=html` and `syntax=html`.

For more info, see Vim’s `:help` on `:syntax`, `'filetype'`, and `:autocmd`.

Comment: I'm hoping not to have to set it manually. I'd like to include it in .exrc or .vimrc. Is this possible?